# How to resolve Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/rxjava.properties

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, rx-java, rx-android

I am using rxjava and rxvolley on my android aplication. When I try to run it I get this error

```
Execution failed for task ':testapp:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/rxjava.properties
            File1: C:\Users\Daniel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.reactivex\rxjava\1.1.0\748f0546d5c3c27f1aef07270ffea0c45f0c42a4\rxjava-1.1.0.jar
            File2: C:\Users\Daniel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.reactivex.rxjava2\rxjava\2.0.3\d2f725668bd22e21170381b23f8fbdf72c69d886\rxjava-2.0.3.jar
```

I have a exclude.gradle file like this

```
android {
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.PROPERTIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/RXJAVA.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/RXJAVA.PROPERTIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava'
    exclude 'META-INF/RXJAVA'
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I had the same problem. The way I fixed it is adding the `packagingOptions` in app gradle as described in [Duplicated file rxjava.properties](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4445#issuecomment-258518265)

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
    }
    buildTypes {
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
}
```

Comment: For an updated answer Refer below as this is outdated

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue.
In my case I am using `Retrofit2` but I assume that the issue is with the `rx libraries`

This is the `build.gradle (module:app)` I am using and in my case works.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.2'

compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0' //<-use this
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.3'    //<-use this

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
```

Anyway there is one better solution as you can see on the top

Comment: No need, use @Julián Martínez solution instead since it's recommended by JakeWharton himself

Comment: If you read this, scroll down, a solution of @Julian is better

Answer (score 3):

I also have the same problem but easily removed duplicated "comment" all Rxjava related dependencies that it doesn't use in my code.

```
//RxJava removes or comment duplicated and not used dependencies.
      //  implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.4.0'
       // implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
       // implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.13'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in build.gradle.app

```
android {
 ...
 ...
 ...

 packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and fixed it by putting below code in app/build.gradle file. Please note that you have to put '*' at the end of path to exclude all the files inside the folder. You will have to change the path of files to be excluded in the below code based on error description.

```
compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'com/google/appengine/repackaged/org/apache/commons/codec/language/bm/*'
        exclude 'com/google/appengine/repackaged/org/codehaus/jackson/impl/*'
        exclude 'com/google/appengine/repackaged/org/apache/commons/codec/language/*'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue today and fixed this problem

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'

//RxJava dependencies
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.0'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.2'
compile 'org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem ,I also used the same method as you ,but because I hava two module ,I only chang it in the module which dependency Rxjava,Finally I  I fixed it is adding the packaginOptions in app gradle

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue in 2019 and above this is most probably because you are using the **deprecated** RxJava 2 CallAdapter.Factory ie

> com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter

you will have to **remove that dependency** and add this

> **implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:latest.version'**

please get the latest version from [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.squareup.retrofit2%20a:adapter-rxjava2)

Answer (score 0):

Normally this kinds of issue occurs due to contain of same package name and class name in two or more libraries which are included in our app level Gradle file. I have faced this issue in runtime and I solved it down grading one of the library.

My issue is here below:

```
Duplicate class a.a found in modules jetified-eSewaSdk-runtime (:eSewaSdk:)
and jetified-khalti-android-2.01.02-runtime (com.khalti:khalti-android:2.01.02)

I downgrade one of the library from com.khalti:khalti-android:2.01.02 to com.khalti:khalti-android:2.00.01
```